# socket.io/1/?t=1437482662157 404 Not found

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, socket.io

I've set up a CoffeeScript with node.js application on a subdomain such as node.domain.com using a port 8901 (http://node.domain.com).

Within my coffeescript app, I'm using socket.io to communicate with the node server and client.

```
socket = io.connect('http://node.domain.com')
```

The problem is doing it that way, I've got an error :

> GET http://node.domain.com/socket.io/1/?t=1437482662157  404 Not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try including the port number in the initialization of socket io.

```
socket = io.connect('http://node.domain.com:8901)
```